# Implict Decleration of Function

Tags: c, function, implicit

First of all I have to said that my brain is burned because of this question. I need to write a function that checks whether the 3rd parameter is a interleaved of 1st and 2nd parameter. I wrote it but when I run it, it gives me this error. "warning: implicit declaration of function ‘interleaved’" Here is my code:

```
void main()
{
    char str1[100] = "ABC";
    char str2[100] = "XYZ";
    char str3[100] = "XAYZBC";

    printf(interleaved(str1, str2, str3));
}
```

```
bool interleaved(char str1[], char str2[], char str3[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    if (strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) != strlen(str3))
        return false;

    while (k < strlen(str3))
    {
        if (i < strlen(str1) && str1[i] == str3[k])
            i++;

        else if (j < strlen(str2) && str2[j] == str3[k])
            j++;
        else
            return false;

        k++;
    }

    if (!(i == strlen(str1) && j == strlen(str2) && k == strlen(str3)))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

I found the faulty part and tried to fix it as follows:

```
void main()
{
    char str1[100] = "ABC";
    char str2[100] = "XYZ";
    char str3[100] = "XAYZBC";

    bool result = interleaved(str1[100], str2[100], str3[100]);
    printf(result);
}
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Is the function `interleaved` is write before or after the main scope?

Comment: Put the `bool interleaved(char str1[], char str2[], char str3[])` function _before_ `main`, or declare it like this `bool interleaved(char str1[], char str2[], char str3[]);` before `main`. **Always** consider this warning as an error.

Comment: @DipStax after the main scope

Answer (score 2):

"Implicit declaration" usually means, at the time when you are trying to use (call) a function, the compiler does not know the function signature / prototype, hence cannot determine the return type and cannot do any check on the argument passing.

Most of the time this is solved by either

- Defining the function before it's use
- [Forward declaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) the function.

That said, your function call and usage of `printf()` is not proper. You can do something like

```
bool result = interleaved(str1[100], str2[100], str3[100]);
printf("%s", result?"yes":"no");
```

Which prints "yes" is the function returns true, and "no" otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare or define functions to use before using them.

Also `bool` is not a correct data to pass as the first argument of `printf()`.

Try this:

```
bool interleaved(char str1[], char str2[], char str3[]); /* declare the function */

int main(void) /* use standard type for main() */
{
    char str1[100] = "ABC";
    char str2[100] = "XYZ";
    char str3[100] = "XAYZBC";

    printf("%s\n", interleaved(str1, str2, str3) ? "true" : "false"); /* correctly use printf() */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the result of `interleaved` (which is a `bool`)  as the format string for `printf`, which is not allowed.

Instead, you need to do something like this:

```
printf("%d", interleaved(str1, str2, str3));
```

---

Also, you need to at least declare `interleaved` before you make a call to that function.